# Give permission to service account to call all Cloud Function in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

As stated [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function), you need to define this block so a service account or user can call the function.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
  project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.project
  region         = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "user:myFunctionInvoker@example.com"
}
```

Is there anyway to give this user/service account to be able call the function without redefining this block repetitively?

### *edit

I add `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` binding to my service account and it works.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
  --member user:USER_EMAIL \
  --role roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

[read more here](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#configuring_a_service_account)

Comment: By "redefining" do you refer to define this policy for every function? If so, grant the permission at project level

Comment: @Puteri yes. I already create a service account that have `Cloud Functions Invoker` role for my API-Gateway. However thw cloud function still askme to run this comand ```gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding docs \
      --region="asia-southeast2" \
      --member="MEMBER_NAME"```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki for everyone's visibility. For a service account or a user to call a function, they need to have the `"roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"` role. To do this on multiple user or to an entire group of user/service account, you can use IAM to manage their access. You can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) on how.